# OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: android, android-menu, openweathermap

How do I change between °C / °F from the android menu with the openweathermap API

[image]

## menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/degrees"
        android:title="Celsius / Fahrenheit"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.menu.menu:
            // How do change between Celsius and Fahrenheit
                break;


        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Dropbox link for a deeper view if needed

[Weather Test app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6l4zbtg8et89qej/owm.zip?dl=0)

Comment: The code you provided just relates to the UI, you need to show the business logic as well to see whats going on.

Comment: @sme My problem is that I am only showing kelvin degrees, and I would like to change it from the menu, but I really have no clue...

Comment: @sme I will upload the code, is not a lot, maybe that way it will be easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OpenWeather Documentation.](https://openweathermap.org/current#data)

Units format

**Description:**

Standard, metric, and imperial units are available.

**Parameters:**

**units** metric, imperial. When you do not use units parameter, format is Standard by default.

> Temperature is available in Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin units.
>
> ```
> For temperature in Fahrenheit use units=imperial
> For temperature in Celsius use units=metric
> Temperature in Kelvin is used by default, no need to use units parameter in API call
> ```
>
> List of all API parameters with units openweathermap.org/weather-data

**Examples of API calls:**

```
standard api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London
metric api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=metric
imperial api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=imperial
```